# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component React,JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

hello everyone I have this call within a hooks I need the lat and lng variables to be saved in the state as I am currently doing it shows me the following error, I hope someone can help me
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const  url = `https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=.....`;
    const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", url);
    http.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
       const data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
       const {location: {lat, lng}} = data;
       const result = {lat, lng} ;
       const  [locations, setLocation] = useState({
            loaded: true,
            coordinates: {
                lat: result.lat,
                lng: result.lng,
            },
            aceptacion:1
        });
        console.log(setLocation);
       return result;
      }
    }
    http.send();
}, []);

return location;
```

};

Comment: Because you're using `useState` inside of the `useEffect`. Move it to be directly inside your functional component definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move useState initialization outside useEffect hook.

```
const [locations, setLocation] = useState({
    loaded: true,
    coordinates: null,
    aceptacion: null,
});

useEffect(() => {
    const  url = `https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=.....`;
    const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", url);
    http.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
       const data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
       const {location: {lat, lng}} = data;
       const result = {lat, lng} ;
       setLocation({
            loaded: true,
            coordinates: {
                lat: result.lat,
                lng: result.lng,
            },
            aceptacion:1
        });
        console.log(setLocation);
        return result;
      }
    }
    http.send();
}, []);

return locations;
```